# Postgresql Merging of two data

Tags: postgresql

I have a inventory table with the following row data.

Row One -> Barcode : SH9025H36SP23,

Row Two -> Barcode : SH9025H36SP23N1

Both are referred as foreign key in other tables.
Row One is old barcode whereas Row Two is the new barcode.

How do i change Row One to Row Two without loosing any references ?

Thank you for taking your time to answer my question.

Simplified Table Structure for Inventory table

```
barcode     varchar   not null  
name        varchar   not null 

PRIMARY KEY (barcode)
```

Referenced by:

```
TABLE "act" CONSTRAINT "actkey" FOREIGN KEY (fkbarcode) REFERENCES inventory(barcode) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT

TABLE "do" CONSTRAINT "dokey" FOREIGN KEY (fkbarcode) REFERENCES inventory(barcode) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

so on..

Comment: In order to adequately answer this question, you'll need to show more of the table structure for both tables -- can you share `\d` output for both the inventory table and the table(s) that references the inventory table?

Comment: Need more information about your query like Error,table structure and Output ?